# Mapping Linking Table with 3 PK's in Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, mapping

right now I'm having trouble mapping a linking table with Hibernate.

First of all I want to explain what I want to map: 
I have 3 tables: Product , DocumentType, Language.

One Product can have each DocumentType (at the moment we have 7 DocumentTypes) in each specific Language (at the moment we have 3 Languages)

That means product "1" can have DocumentType "A" in language "EN", "ES" and "FR".

I created a linking table with 3 foreign keys which are also composite primary key.

Here is how my sql looks like.

```
CREATE TABLE Person(
  id int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name varchar(255)
);

CREATE TABLE DocumentType(
  id int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name varchar(255),
  key varchar(255)
);

CREATE TABLE Language(
  id int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name varchar(255),
  code varchar(2)
);

CREATE TABLE Person_DocumentType_Language(
  person_id int NOT NULL,
  doc_id int NOT NULL,
  lang_id NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY(person_id)
    REFERENCES Person(id),
  FOREIGN KEY(doc_id)
    REFERENCES DocumentType(id),
  FOREIGN KEY(lang_id)
    REFERENCES Language(id),
  PRIMARY KEY(person_id, doc_id, lang_id)
);
```

With the last linking table I could tell which Person has which DocumentTypes and in which Languages.
I'm mostly interested in the information which DocumentType has which Language for one Person.

Say I'm Person A. Now I want to know which DocumentTypes I have with which Languages. In SQL it would look like this I think:

```
Select doc_id, lang_id from Person_DocumentType_Language where person_id=1
```

Does that make sense? And how could I map this in Hibernate?

Answer (score 0):

One approach is have a `Map` from `DocumentType` to `Language`. I'm a bit rusty on the exact annotation, but here is a start:

```
public class Person {

    @Id
    public int id;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity=Language.class)
    @MapKeyClass(Integer.class)
    @CollectionTable(name="Person_DocumentType_Language")
    @MapKeyColumn(name="doc_id")
    public Map<DocumentType,Language> docTypeLang;
}
```